# pyspark - fill null date values with an old date

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyspark

**Question**: Following code fails to replace null date values to `12/31/1900` in a date column. What I may be doing wrong here, and how can we fix the issue?

Dataframe `df` is loaded from a Data file has a column `Order_date` with values in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. I'm importing this data file into a SQL table of `Azure SQL Db` that has a corresponding column with same name `Order_date`. Following code successfully imports data into SQL table. But the null values in `Order_date` column are not replaced with `12/31/1900`:

**Remarks**:

1. The `Order_date` column in SQL table has to be of datatype `date`
2. For `Order_date` column, when I tried the following, I got the error saying dataframe column is of StringType and destination column is of DateType. `.withColumn("Order_date",F.when(df.Order_date.isNull(),to_date(lit("12/31/1900"),"'MM/dd/yyyy'")).otherwise(df.Order_date))`

.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
......
df1 = df.withColumn("CustomerID", df.CustomerID.cast(IntegerType())) \
 .withColumn("Order_date", F.to_date(col('Order_date'), 'MM/dd/yyyy'))

df2 = df1.fillna({'Order_date': '12/31/1900'})

#load df2 into SQL table
df2.write(.....)
```

Comment: `'12/31/1900'` is a string? `functions.to_date` creates a formatted date column - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date  with a defined representations string - but it is still a date column. Try setting a date. Do you get any stacktrace / error? if so, edit it into your question. Did you try to set it to a `date` not a `string`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tried `datetime.date(1900, 12, 31)` and got the error: `descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object`. Is that what you meant - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider replacing the `null` and empty string values in `Order_date` before performing your `to_date()` conversion, e.g.:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Example').getOrCreate()
data = [
    { 'Order_date': '02/28/1997'},
    { 'Order_date': ''},
    { 'Order_date': None}
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
# +----------+                                                                    
# |Order_date|
# +----------+
# |02/28/1997|
# |          |
# |      null|
# +----------+

df2 = df.withColumn('Order_date2', F.col('Order_date'))
df2 = df2.na.replace('', '01/01/1900', 'Order_date2') # Replaces empty strings
df2 = df2.na.fill({'Order_date2': '01/01/1900'}) # Replaces `null` values
df2.show()
# +----------+-----------+
# |Order_date|Order_date2|
# +----------+-----------+
# |02/28/1997| 02/28/1997|
# |          | 01/01/1900|
# |      null| 01/01/1900|
# +----------+-----------+

df3 = df2.withColumn('Order_date3', F.to_date(df2.Order_date2, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
df3.show()
# +----------+-----------+-----------+
# |Order_date|Order_date2|Order_date3|
# +----------+-----------+-----------+
# |02/28/1997| 02/28/1997| 1997-02-28|
# |          | 01/01/1900| 1900-01-01|
# |      null| 01/01/1900| 1900-01-01|
# +----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I did not apply all your suggestions. But your suggestions helped me resolved the issue (thank you). I had already replaced null strings with empty strings, so using `subset` parameter of [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html) method, I replaced empty stings in the date column to an old date before the code shown in my post above. And that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether null is causing issue.

in pyspark if column is empty then it will be treated as null

example :

```
Source csv Data:

Order_date|CustomerID
11-10-2022|89296
12-10-2022|67760
|879798

>>> df = spark.read.csv("/Path to csv/sample1.csv", sep="|", header="true", inferSchema="false")

>>> df.show()
+----------+----------+
|Order_date|CustomerID|
+----------+----------+
|11-10-2022|     89296|
|12-10-2022|     67760|
|      null|    879798|
+----------+----------+

>>> df.filter("Order_date is NULL").show()
+----------+----------+
|Order_date|CustomerID|
+----------+----------+
|      null|    879798|
+----------+----------+

whereas if it is hardcoded null in data then it will be treated as string type

Source csv data :

Order_date|CustomerID
11-10-2022|89296
12-10-2022|67760
null|879798

>>> df_test = spark.read.csv("/path to csv/sample1.csv", sep="|", header="true", inferSchema="false")
>>> df_test.show()
+----------+----------+
|Order_date|CustomerID|
+----------+----------+
|11-10-2022|     89296|
|12-10-2022|     67760|
|      null|    879798|
+----------+----------+


>>> df_test.filter("Order_date=='null'").show()
+----------+----------+
|Order_date|CustomerID|
+----------+----------+
|      null|    879798|
+----------+----------+
```