# Null value appeared in non-nullable field

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to write the following pyspark dataframe to csv by using

```
df_final.write.csv("v1_results/run1",header=True, emptyValue='',nullValue='')
```

Please help me locate on why this issue

Below is the schema associated with the dataframe

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |--  id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sim: float (nullable = true)
```

Below is the stack of the error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 16 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 16.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 1074) (cluster-a183-w-1.us-central1-c.c.analytics-online-data-sci-thd.internal executor 8): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while decoding: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field:
- array element class: "scala.Double"
- root class: "scala.collection.Seq"
If the schema is inferred from a Scala tuple/case class, or a Java bean, please try to use scala.Option[_] or other nullable types (e.g. java.lang.Integer instead of int/scala.Int).
mapobjects(lambdavariable(MapObject, DoubleType, true, -1), assertnotnull(lambdavariable(MapObject, DoubleType, true, -1)), input[0, array<double>, true], Some(interface scala.collection.Seq))
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$Deserializer.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$scalaConverter$2(ScalaUDF.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1160)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1176)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1214)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:232)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field:
- array element class: "scala.Double"
- root class: "scala.collection.Seq"
If the schema is inferred from a Scala tuple/case class, or a Java bean, please try to use scala.Option[_] or other nullable types (e.g. java.lang.Integer instead of int/scala.Int).
```

Comment: I think the question lacks details. What's the problem? If the problem is that you think you don't have nulls, but apparently you have, try to locate them (e.g. `.filter(df_final.sim.isNull())`) and work backwards identifying, how they appeared. FYI, `nullValue=''` changes `''` into *null*, so having it, you would create nulls while using `write`, even you didn't have them before.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591277/18920194